# Responsive HTML5 Video where aspect ratio can change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up a HTML5 video player using video.js and Flat UI by DesignModo. I have the problem that I need to make the video player responsive, so the width needs to be 100%.

The problem is that then when this is set the height of the video is always the same as you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q8BU/). So what I need (I think) is a script which detects the aspect ratio as the **aspect ratio will change**. I found a script like that [over here](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) however it is designed for `iframe` videos like YouTube or Vimeo.

I attempted to modify the script by changing the value of `$allVideos` to `$("video[class^='video-js']"),` but it does not seem to have worked. Can anyone have a look at [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q8BU/) and try and tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

---

By the way, I know that the links to the font files and image(s) are turning up 404, thats because at the moment the files are not hosted on my server, I have just been testing them locally.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `height: 100%;` from `.video-js .vjs-tech`. And this take aspect ratio automatically from given width 100%.

Comment: .vjs-tech is a required class that is added by video.js on page load. Please inspect the video player after it has loaded to see this.